# Html boxes not displaying properly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have two div boxes one next to each other and having the same height as a percentage so that they show correctly on two different screens with different sizes.

The sceens appear to have different sizes when I run the code.

Here is my code:

```
 <a href="https://unesco.csod.com/catalog/SearchAdvanced.aspx?dept_id=538">
<div style="border-radius: 25px; width: 40%; height: 56%; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; margin-left: 7%; display: inline-block; background-color: #80b280; flat: left;"><strong><span style="padding-top: 20px; font-size: 20px;"><br />
IT Training Resources</span><br />
</strong>
<br />
<span style="font-size: 13px;"><font face="Tahoma">A comprehensive resource page which includes video tutorials on a variety of Microsoft products<br />
</font>
</span></div>
</a>
<a href="https://unesco.csod.com/catalog/SearchAdvanced.aspx?dept_id=533">
<div style="border-radius: 25px; width: 40%; height: 56%; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; margin-right: 7%; float: right; display: inline-block; background-color: #5cadff;"><strong><span style="font-size: 20px; margin-top: 20%;">
<br />
Career Tutorials Library</span>
</strong>
<br />
<br />
<span style="font-size: 13px;"><font face="Tahoma">Rapid courses for all staff to move ahead in their career</font><br />
</span></div>
</a>
```

And here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eKpF9/

Comment: I am using Chrome and they appear to be showing correctly. can you give us a screen shot of it `appearing to have different sizes'

Comment: the height is changing with the amount of text inside each Div, but that is the only thing that I can see.

Comment: @Malachi, I have the constraint of using chrome

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a "global" div containing the other two divs with a height defined so that the browser can do de percentage of that value.

```
<div style="height:500px">
    rest if your code
</div>
```

if you don't want to define a fixed height to the div you can use the javascript property screen.height to get the height of the screen and then set it has the div height.

Comment: Was about to say that. I edited the Fiddle to show this: http://jsfiddle.net/CH93S/

Comment: Absolutely right, and there is a good reason behind having to set a defined height on the parent. Otherwise, if your parent element has a height of auto, it's height is calculated based on the height of its children. If its children have a percentage-based height value, their height is based on the height of its parent... which is based on the height of its children - infinite loop!

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that this global div needs to be defined in percentage so that it shows similarly on both screen.. the number of pixels affects the way it is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy: you have a br less in the right box. Floated elements do not have heights. Also you misspelled float once :)

Comment: Also one `<span>` has `margin-top` and the other has `padding-top` too.